# AJAX update MYSQL database using function called from HTML generated from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, ajax

I have a php page generating and displaying a table. for the last row in the table i want to display an image with an 'onclick' function attached. this will send the username for the selected row to a script that will use AJAX to update a database. The table displays fine but the AJAX is not working. my php to display the image is:

```
echo "<td> <img id='tblimg' 
    onclick='like('" . $row['Username'] . "')' 
    src='like.jpg' alt='like/dislike image' 
    width='80px' height='30px'></td>";
```

The javascript function is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

        function like(user) 
        {

            $.ajax(
                url: "update.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: { 'username': user, 'liked': '1' },                   
                success: function()
                            {
                                alert("ok");                                    
                            }
            );
        }

</script>
```

And here is update.php:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("","sam74","********","sam74");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$Username = $_POST['username'];
$Liked = $_POST['liked'];   

$sql = "UPDATE 'followers' SET 'Liked' = '$Liked' WHERE 'Username' = '$Username'";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

Comment: You can try Firebug and see what response you are getting after calling update.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes in this code, let me help you line by line.

```
echo "<td> <img id='tblimg' 
onclick=\'like('" . $row['Username'] . "');\' 
src='like.jpg' alt='like/dislike image' 
width='80px' height='30px'></td>";
```

The javascript function is:

Escape your quotes for the onclick event first

```
    function like(user) 
    {

        $.ajax({
            url: "update.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { 'username': user, 'liked': '1' },                   
            success: function()
                        {
                            alert("ok");                                    
                        }
        });
    }
```

add { and } to the ajax call

Remove the quotes from table name and fields

```
$sql = "UPDATE followers SET Liked = '$Liked' WHERE Username = '$Username'";
```

in ajax success and after the function begins, you can always print a message to see if your function is being called, and if php script is returning some error, use an alert for that

**UPDATE**

```
success: function(data){
   alert(data); // this will print you any php / mysql error as an alert                                    
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Write your onclick option like this.

```
echo "<img onclick=\"like('" . $row['Username']. "');\" 
src='like.jpg' alt='like/dislike image' 
width='80px' height='30px' />";
```

Comment: Check the added code after "UPDATE" on my answer, if it helped you let me know.

Comment: Helped a lot thanks. I also installed firebug and that has been helping me with actually being able to see what has been posted to update.php. I now have it working when i create a copy of the img element i am trying to display from the php echo somewhere else on the page. Still trying to get my head around the quotes in the echo. What are the backslashes for? the echo i currently an trying is this:

echo "<td> <img id='tblimg' 
 src = 'like.jpg'
 alt = 'pic' 
 width = '80' 
 height = '30' 
 onclick = 'like('" . $row['Username'] . "')'
 > </td>";

not sure what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

The `jQuery.ajax()` function expects an object to be passed; you need to use `{` and `}` to begin and end your object literal. What you currently have is invalid JavaScript syntax, if you checked your browser's developer tools you'd see an error indicating that. So:

```
$.ajax(
    url: "update.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        'username': user,
        'liked': '1'
    },
    success: function () {
        alert("ok");
    }
);
```

should be

```
$.ajax({ // added {
    url: "update.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        'username': user,
        'liked': '1'
    },
    success: function () {
        alert("ok");
    }
}); // added }
```