# how to update database with onclick function

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, mysqli

how do i create a function with onclick?

```
<?php if ($displayStatus['status'] == "Active") {?>
    <button class="selected"><a href="#" onclick="return getSuccessOutput">Active</a></button><br><br>
<?php } else {?>
    <button class="seedo"><a href="#" onclick="return getSuccessOutput" >Active</a></button><br><br>
<?php } ?>
```

[image for status button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFJAp.png)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getSuccessOutput() {
     //enter code here???
    }
</script>


$HOST = "localhost";
$USERNAME = 'root';
$PASSWORD = '';
$DB = 'DB';
```

the function is like if i would select the active button, upon clicking on the button, it will update the database and change the status in the DB "Status" row to Active.

Comment: Create PHP file and do Ajax and if success change the button class

Comment: @user3230289 above suggested flow is developed in my code hope will work for you..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can not update any record in database by using javascript function.
You must need to use ajax request in your function that you are using on onclick and than add a new PHP file and write your query in this file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="updateAction.php" method="post">    
<button type="submit" class="selected">Active</button>
</form>
```

and write your update code in updateAction.php

Answer (score 0):

In Your HTML File

```
<?php if ($displayStatus['status'] == "Active"){?>
<button class="selected"><a href="#" onclick="return getSuccessOutput()">Active</a></button><br><br>

<?php } else {?>
 <button class="seedo"><a href="#" onclick="return getSuccessOutput()" >Active</a></button><br><br>
 <?php }

<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
```

**in ajax.js do somthing like this**

```
    $.post(site_url.concat('cert.php') , { special_code:'you_can_send' } , function(data){
           // dom something here
    });
```

**create a process.php , You have to process the info which you are getting through $_POST method**

```
$HOST = "localhost";
$USERNAME = 'root';
$PASSWORD = '';
$DB = 'DB';

// your script here
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a php file and use ajax. and more detail check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20404407/ajax-update-mysql-database-using-function-called-from-html-generated-from-php). meet your question answer.

Answer (score 0):

**HERE IS YOUR COMPLETE CODE AS PER YOUR NEED HAVE A LOOK AND LEARN AND THEN TRY OUR OWN**

**Note:**

**in index.php page i have given static value '1' to hidden input you need to change value by passing your record id.and also change value of $status=$displayStatus['status']**

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

<?php 
  $status="Active";
  if($status=="Active"){ ?>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" id="recordId"/>
  <button  class="chageStatus" value="Active"><a href="#">Active</a></button><br><br>
<?php }else{ ?>    
  <button class="chageStatus" value="Inactive"><a href="#">Inactive</a></button><br><br>
  <?php }?>

  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery('.chageStatus').on('click',function(){
          $.ajax({
            url:'changeStatus.php',
            type:'post',
            data:{'status':jQuery(this).val(),id:jQuery('#recordId').val()},
          }).success(function(response){
              alert(response);
          });
       });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**changeStatus.php**

```
<?php 
echo $recordId=$_POST['id'];
echo "</br>";
echo $status=$_POST['status'];


// do connection and update the status of $recordId and its updated value will be $status
?>
```

Comment: actually i still dont know how to use this code. i have 2 button , one is active and other is inactive. i will have a query to get the status from the DB. if it state active, the button will be different colour from inactive. if user wan to change the state to inactive, by clicking the inactive button, it will update the DB status to inactive and the button colour will change to be the selected one

Comment: above given code is completely as per your need just set $status=value from db which you have already got using db query and set  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" id="recordId"/> change value="1" to value="urVariable" in which you have id of that record

Comment: $get = "SELECT * FROM status";
$link = mysqli_query($link, $get)or die(mysqli_error($link));
$display = mysqli_fetch_array($link);


  $status= $display['status'];
  if($status=="Active"){ ?>
      <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $display['status_id']?>" id="recordId"/>
  <button  class="chageStatus" value="Active"><a href="#">Active</a></button><br><br>
<?php }else{ ?>    
  <button class="chageStatus" value="Inactive"><a href="#">Inactive</a></button><br><br>
  <?php }?>

Comment: will you pls let me know of what status do you want to change status?

Comment: i the table "status", there are 2 column ( status_id ,status). in the column "status" i can only have either active or inactive. 
(status_id : 1 , status : Active)
if user decided to change the active to inactive, by clicking on the "inactive button". the database will change the "active" to "inactive" by clicking the button, only the button colour will switch and not refresh the page.

Comment: ok now clear your need there is two button active and inative now what next?

Comment: the button is for me to maintain another page. so if the status is active,  it will display all data that is active in another PHP page. those status are inactive wont be display out.

Comment: show me table status and if status active then which data you want to show?